# Opening shared drive directory with variable opens default documents folder vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to open a shared drive based on a variable. It works fine if I try open the drive without trying
to use a variable but with the variable it opens documents folder.

Pete

```
function opendirectory( nwk as string)    'here I passed the 2804544 via nwk    
 Dim teststr teststr3 As String
        teststr = Chr(34) & "\\shared_drive\directory\2804544" & Chr(34)
        teststr3 = Chr(34) & "\\shared_drive\directory\" & nwk & Chr(34)

' I put the if statement to check if both are the same. If I hover over each they LOOK identical but obviously they are not.
        If teststr = teststr3 Then
            x = x + 1 ' I put a breakpoint on this line, which never gets hit
        End If
        Process.Start("explorer.exe", teststr3) 'This opens documents directory
        Process.Start("explorer.exe", teststr)  'This opens the correct directory
end function
```

I've tried different combinations but can figure out how to combine the shared drive text with a variable.

Comment: teststr3 misses a trailing "\" before ```& nwk``` compared to teststr.

Comment: Ooops , I didn't copy it over properly \ , I double checked and it is there in my working code I corrected the copied text above.

Comment: I bet there's an extra invisble character (space?) in ```nwk```. Try nwk.Trim().

Comment: Tried the nwk.Trim() and also put "\\shared_drive\directory\"  into teststr3 then trimmed both with  teststr = teststr3.Trim() + nwk.Trim() and both just open the documents directory.

Comment: For troubleshooting, change the signature of your method from (nwk as String) to (nwk as Integer).  If your value has some hidden non-numerics the code will throw a useful exception.

Comment: Changed it to integer , no error but same result , opens document folder .

Comment: OK got it to work but dang what a roundabout way.First I load teststr2 = "\\shared_drive\directory\"   then I add the nwkdrv to it  teststr3 =  teststr2.Trim() & nwkdrv finally wrap it in chr(34)'s teststr = Chr(34) & teststr3 & Chr(34)